# Adding values in a string with html code

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

i want to put the values inside the >< , but i couldn't do it because the errors of the "" start appearing.
Thanks!

```
string Nome = reader.GetString(1);
            string Tipo = reader.GetString(2);
            int Preco = reader.GetInt32(3);
            string Horario = reader.GetString(4);
            htmlStr += @"<div>
                        < img class=""imagem"" src=""imagens/comer/pino.jpg"">
                        <p class=""my_p""></p>
                        <p class=""my_p1""></p>
                        <p class=""my_p2""></p>
                        <p class=""my_p3""></p>
                        <p class=""morada""></p>
                        <div class=""row"" style=""margin-top: -7px"">
                            <button class=""btn_reser"" onclick=""location.href='registo.aspx';"" type=""button"">Reservar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>";
```

Comment: You can use `'` instead of `"` for html attributes. Example: `<img class='imagem'>`, but then you run afoul in the onclick.. What exactly is going wrong with this - What error message do you get?

Comment: forget the onclick, this code is from php version, so i'm still working on it, the problem now is to put the variables inside the tags <p class=""my_p"">Nome</p> and i can't find a way :s

Comment: so is anything wrong with using `<p class='my_p'>Nome</p>`?

Comment: i think so, because i read in other posts that you must put like this >"+Nome+"< but it shows error

Comment: Try putting an `@` before the new string: `>"+Nome+@"<`, although really there are better ways of doing this.

Comment: yap it worked :D thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Use \" instead of "" and use [string.Format()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) to insert strings into another string...

```
string p = "paragraph 0";
string p1 = "paragraph 1";
string p2 = "paragraph 2";
string p3 = "paragraph 3";
string p4 = "paragraph 4";

string htmlStr = string.Format("<div>" +
            "< img class=\"imagem\" src=\"imagens/comer/pino.jpg\">" +
            "<p class=\"my_p\">{0}</p>" +
            "<p class=\"my_p1\">{1}</p>" +
            "<p class=\"my_p2\">{2}</p>" +
            "<p class=\"my_p3\">{3}</p>" +
            "<p class=\"morada\">{4}</p>" +
            "<div class=\"row\" style=\"margin-top: -7px\">" +
                "<button class=\"btn_reser\" onclick=\"location.href='registo.aspx';\" type=\"button\">Reservar</button>" +
            "</div>" +
        "</div>", p, p1, p2, p3, p4);
```

Comment: `""` works perfectly fine to escape quotes in verbatim strings (those that start with `@`)

Comment: Yes, however I think escaping helps a little with readability.